# ThreadAbortException when running nunit test with Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, nunit

I have the following classes. I am trying to test the component that I built but its throwing ThreadAbortException and I'm unable to fix the issue. Following is the code I've written

This is on codebehind of

> UserPromptWPS.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserPromptWPS : Window
{            
        public bool WPSButtonFailed { get; set; }
        public bool WPSButtonPassed { get; set; }
        public bool DoTest { get; set; }   
        
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private WebDriverWait wait;

        public UserPromptWPS(IWebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait)
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
            this.driver = driver;
            this.wait = wait;     

   
            Loaded += UserPromptWPS_Loaded;                
        }

        private async void UserPromptWPS_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            WPSButton wpsButton = new WPSButton();   

        
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
               while(true)
               {
                  if(wpsButton.ClickWPS(driver,wait))
                  {
                      break;
                  }
               }
                
            });
            this.Close();
        }
}
```

Here WPSButton is an object I'm calling. And below is the NUnit test I've written.

> NUnit Test

```
[TestFixture]
public class WPSButtonTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ExecuteClickWPS_Success_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        var result = false;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            LoginWebGui loginWebGui = new LoginWebGui();
            ClearLog clearLog = new ClearLog();
            WPSButton wpsButton = new WPSButton();
            LogoutWebGui logoutWebGui = new LogoutWebGui();

            var webDriverSetup = new WebDriverSetup();
            var driver = webDriverSetup.WebDriver;
            var wait = webDriverSetup.Wait;
            loginWebGui.ExecuteLogin(driver, wait);
            clearLog.ExecuteClearLog(driver, wait);

            UserPromptWPS userPromptWPS = new UserPromptWPS(driver, wait);
            userPromptWPS.Closed += (s, e) => userPromptWPS.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            userPromptWPS.ShowDialog();                
            
            result = userPromptWPS.WPSButtonPassed;
        }));

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();           

        Assert.That(result, Is.True);
        
    }
}
```

Here running this unit test throwing ThreadAbortException error. What I'm trying to achieve here is to run an infinite loop when 'UserPromptWPS' window is open and upon (if) condition is met then break the loop and close the window. I couldn't fix the issue of why am I getting ThreadAbortException error.
If someone could help me out please.

Comment: have you tried to surround the code inside the delegate with a try/catch to see why is throwing?

Comment: @marsalal1014 nothing happens. But in the class that im calling that is the 'wps.ClickWPS' also I'm using try and catch it shows threadabortexception there. I tested that class with another unit test and that works fine. Problem is something with the thread.delegate here.

Comment: do you use any of these methods `Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer` on your code? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/threadabortexception-occurs-you-use-response-end

Comment: No none of them @marsalal1014. I'm working with .net wpf not asp.net

Comment: An STA thread requires a message loop, and I'm not sure if `ShowDialog` by itself qualifies.

Comment: @StephenCleary even .Show() doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: I would use [something like `WpfContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncCTPUtil/blob/master/AsyncTestUtilities/WpfContext.cs).

Comment: I wouldn't create a button in one thread and then use it in another(on thread pool) without using dispatcher.

Comment: @Rekshino well the WPSButton is just the name of the class. Well I was able to keep the window open with app.Run(userPromptWPS). But the process is not ending instead on debugger mode its throwing : <System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it> this exception error